# MVC3 Hyperlink Right Click Form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, form-submit, right-click

I have an MVC3 C# .Net web app.  We have a grid where the left most column is a submit button per each row. This button is styled to look like a hyperlink.  The functionality works just fine for a left mouse click.  However, the Customer has requested that the hyperlinks allow the standard Right Click actions of "Open in New Tab" and "Open in New Window".  I am working in our development environment and I have swapped out the submit button in the grid for a hyperlink.  Left click works fine, however, Right Clicking on the hyperlink does not produce a submit of the form.  Is there a way to perform a submit of the form on Right Click "Open in New Tab" or "Open in New Window" ?

Comment: Is it ok to pass the information(form values) via url(GET)?

Comment: @Soosh...yes..that is ok